# Trazer a soma de IDS e dados em duas tabelas usando SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso fazer um SQL para que me trague os dados de:

```
`DATA | QTDE IDTa | QTDE IDTb | VALORa | VALORb | Saldo (diferença de VALORa - VALORb) `
```

Porém não estou conseguindo trazer os dados corretamente com esse SQL segue exemplo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nU2Ds1qon4jXJd1jk24spQ/1

preciso que saia assim:

```
    DATA   | TITULOS A PAGAR | TITULOS A RECEBER | VALOR A RECEBER | VALOR A PAGAR | SALDO
01/10/2018 |         5       |         5         |    R$ 30.000    |  28.000       |  R$ 2.000
```

Nesse caso ele precisa somar todos os IDs da tabela baixagasto enquanto a data de vencimento for igual a data de vencimento, ou seja quero saber quantos títulos vence a cada dia assim como os que tenho para pagar a cada dia e exibir o saldo a diferença dos dois.

Comment: Você precisa dar um exemplo da saída real que você deseja no caso desses dados de exemplo que você informou

Comment: Opa, sim claro.
editei a pergunta e coloquei como preciso da saída exata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem algumas coisas que eu acho que tu precisa levar em consideração, primeiro é teu JOIN, ele não tem um ON e olhando a estrutura das duas tabelas eu não vejo uma ligação entre elas para um JOIN.

Outra coisa é a falta de um GROUP BY para ficar claro por qual coluna (imagino pela tua saída que seja a data) tu está agrupando itens para somar.

Eu faria a união de dois selects distintos (um de receita e um de gasto, sendo o de gasto com valores negativos), agruparia o resultado por data e somarias os valores todos (como gasto é negativo na soma ele iria subtrair

```
SELECT U.datavencto, SUM(U.valorprogramado)
FROM (
    SELECT datavencto, valorprogramado
    FROM baixareceita

    UNION ALL

    SELECT datavencto, valorprogramado * (-1)
    FROM baixagasto
) U
GROUP BY U.datavencto
```

**[EDIT]**

Coloquei os outros campos que tu queria como retorno

```
SELECT U.datavencto, SUM(U.qtd_receber), SUM(U.qtd_pagar), SUM(U.valor_receber), SUM(U.valor_pagar), SUM(U.valor_total)
FROM (
    SELECT datavencto, COUNT(idbaixareceita) AS qtd_receber, 0 AS qtd_pagar, SUM(valorprogramado) AS valor_receber, 0 AS valor_pagar, SUM(valorprogramado) AS valor_total
    FROM baixareceita
    GROUP BY datavencto

    UNION ALL

    SELECT datavencto, 0 AS qtd_receber, COUNT(idbaixagasto) AS qtd_pagar, 0 AS valor_receber, SUM(valorprogramado) AS valor_pagar, SUM(valorprogramado)*(-1) AS valor_total
    FROM baixagasto
    GROUP BY datavencto
) U
GROUP BY U.datavencto
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo código,
Ajudou demais.
Valeu mesmo.